# entityManager.createNativeQuery fails with SQL error when executed for an entity annotated with @Formula. How to fix this?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, criteria-api

I am using Java 17 and Hibernate 6, trying to run a simple select query using EntityManager's createNativeQuery method as follows:

```
resultList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(nativeJSONQuery, tclass)
        .setFirstResult(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize())
        .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize()).getResultList();
```

But this raises the Postgres SQL error:

```
`The column name parentName was not found in this ResultSet.`
```

where parentName is a computed entity column annotated with Hibernate's @Formula annotation as follows:

```
    @Formula("(select c.name from customer c where c.id = parent_id)")
    private String parentName;
```

The same query works OK for other entities without a @Formula column. Does anyone have an idea how to get this scenario to work?

The select-query being used here is as follows:

```
nativeJSONQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
nativeJSONQuery += " ORDER BY json_fields_data->>'" + orderByField;
nativeJSONQuery += orderAscending ? "' ASC" : "' DESC";
```

I've tried using entityManager.createQuery() instead of createNativeQuery() but couldn't figure out how to sort by a JSONB field's inner keys that way. In the larger context, I also need to be able to filter by the values of the JSON field's keys, which is why I opted for createNativeQuery.

Any help would be much appreciated.